# MongoDB starting error

Tags: mongodb

Well recently i want to start the mongodb server but when i tried to use the command line: mongod on my windows x32 with the mongodb version : 3.2.18 ,i got the follwing error:

```
2017-12-29T10:45:56.427+0100 I CONTROL  [main]
2017-12-29T10:45:56.427+0100 W CONTROL  [main] 32-bit servers don't have journal
ing enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
2017-12-29T10:45:56.427+0100 I CONTROL  [main]
2017-12-29T10:45:56.437+0100 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update
is installed, no need to zero-out data files
2017-12-29T10:45:56.437+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7
556 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 32-bit host=ROOT-PC
2017-12-29T10:45:56.437+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows Vis
ta/Windows Server 2008
2017-12-29T10:45:56.437+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.18
2017-12-29T10:45:56.437+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 4c1bae566c0
c00f996a2feb16febf84936ecaf6f
2017-12-29T10:45:56.447+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-12-29T10:45:56.447+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-12-29T10:45:56.447+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-12-29T10:45:56.447+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: i386
2017-12-29T10:45:56.447+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: i386
2017-12-29T10:45:56.447+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-12-29T10:45:56.447+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndList
en: 28663 Cannot start server. The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not av
ailable with this build of mongod. Please specify a different storage engine exp
licitly, e.g. --storageEngine=mmapv1., terminating
2017-12-29T10:45:56.447+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Comment: @MohamedSameer thank you, it worked fine, i searched for some issues like that but i did not find the good one... Thanks again it working fine :)

Comment: Good to hear :)

Comment: And what if i tried to use the following command to import a db :  mongoimport --db abcd --collection res C:\Users\ROOT\Desktop\workspace\MONGODB\rest.json and it shows the following error: 2017-12-29T14:26:00.568+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:14

Answer (score 0):

The WiredTiger storage engine is only available in the 64-bit version of MongoDB ([source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/)).

As the error message says, you have to provide another storage engine explicitly via the `--storageEngine` command line option.